# TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat' after display multiple pictures in a folder using opencv

Tags: python, opencv

When I run this code

```
import cv2 as cv
import glob

path=glob.glob("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/python/*.jpg")

for i in path:
    
    #print(i)
    
    img=cv.imread(i)
    
    cv.imshow('Image',i)

    cv.WaitKey(0)

    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

I get the following error:

`TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'mat'`

What it should be the cause ?

Comment: the second argument of imshow should be img not i

Answer (score 2):

change `cv.imshow('Image',i)` to  `cv.imshow('Image',img)`

you do not need  `destroyAllWindows()` inside the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Refactor to this

```
import cv2 as cv
import glob

path=glob.glob("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/python/*.jpg")

for i in path:
    
    #print(i)
    
    img=cv.imread(i)
    
    cv.imshow('Image'+str(i),img)

cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```